# Complex multi table mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Im Looking for some help with a mysql query to return the below data from a few different tables for my international call billing system

In the database i have a table that contains each of the call records, billing rates & the final group which i want to display on the invoice.

What im looking to do is iterate through the table tbl_international_rates and for each row sum the CDR_ChargedDurationMinutes in tbl_international_records WHERE CDR_BillerCode=international_rate_prefix then * international_rate_price returing a total amount of charged minutes and a prefix total or something that looks like the below.

```
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|        Prefix            |      total minutes       | total amount         |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|         93               |          14.3            |         $137.28          |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|         937              |          31.2            |         $418.08          |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
```

once that is complete i would like to group them together by there parent group returning something from mysql that look like the below table.

```
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|  CountryDescription      |   CountryTotalMinutes    |      CountryTotalCosts   |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|        Afghanistan       |         45.5             |           555.36         |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
```

is this possible?

This is the structure of the table in the database

tbl_international_groups

```
|--------------------------|--------------------------------|
| international_group_idno | international_group_description|
|--------------------------|--------------------------------|
|            1             |         Afghanistan            |
|--------------------------|--------------------------------|
|            2             |         USA                    |
|--------------------------|--------------------------------|
```

tbl_international_rates

```
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
| international_rate_idno  | international_rate_prefix| international_rate_group | international_rate_price |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|            1             |         93               |          1               |          9.60            |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|            1             |         937              |          1               |          13.40           |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
```

tbl_international_records

```
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|          CDR_ID          |CDR_ChargedDurationMinutes|      CDR_BillerCode      |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|            1             |         4.7              |           93             |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|            2             |         5.6              |           97             |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|            3             |         9.6              |           93             |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|            4             |         25.6             |           97             |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
```

****EDIT******

Using the below query i am able to return the table like the below however how can i group them by there parent in tbl_international_groups

```
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|        Prefix            |      total minutes       | total amount         |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|         93               |          14.3            |         $137.28          |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|         937              |          31.2            |         $418.08          |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
```

The Query

```
select rates.international_rate_prefix as Prefix
 , sum( records.CDR_ChargedDurationMinutes ) as total_minutes
 , sum( records.CDR_ChargedDurationMinutes ) * 
rates.international_rate_retail as total_amount
from tbl_international_rates as rates
join tbl_international_records as records
  on rates.international_rate_prefix = records.CDR_BillerCode
group by rates.international_rate_prefix
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: did my solution give you your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it. This is my solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eb3b1/23

```
select international_group_description as CountryDescription,
 sum(total_minutes) as CountryTotalMinutes,
 sum(total_amount) as CountryTotalCosts
from (
  select rates.international_rate_group, 
  rates.international_rate_prefix as Prefix
  , round(sum( records.CDR_ChargedDurationMinutes ), 2) as total_minutes
  , round(sum( records.CDR_ChargedDurationMinutes ) * 
   rates.international_rate_price, 2) as total_amount
  from tbl_international_rates as rates
  join tbl_international_records as records
    on rates.international_rate_prefix = records.CDR_BillerCode
  join tbl_international_groups groups
    on rates.international_rate_group = 
  groups.international_group_idno
  group by rates.international_rate_prefix
 ) as subselect
join tbl_international_groups groups
on groups.international_group_idno = subselect.international_rate_group
```

Comment: This Query looks to be working inside mysql which is returning for each rate however how would i group them by each country. i have an average knowledge of mysql just not complex queries. i noticed this still also returns some duplicate prefixes instead of 1 single prefix per row with the calculated results

Comment: I see no functional dependency here. You cannot select `a` and `b * c` but only group by `b`